# Is there a word for wanting bad things to happen to others?

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

The German word **schadenfreude** is often used in English to express the pleasure derived from seeing misery in others.

From dictionary.reference.com

> ***schadenfreude*** *noun.* satisfaction or pleasure felt at someone else's misfortune.

For example quite harmlessly, finding it funny when someone trips over, or more dramatically the pleasure derived when seeing your ex-partner go through a messy break up.

Is there a word for *wanting* bad things to happen to others? The context would typically a bit a jilted lover or a jealous person.

For example hoping someone's holiday goes badly, or hoping the company project goes badly after you leave.

Comment: 'Ill will' and synonyms (eg hostility; rancour) surely include this sense.

Comment: *Malevolence* means literally "wishing evil" upon someone, though it's also (and perhaps more often) employed to mean "enacting evil" upon someone.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I think rancour merits an answer at least.

Comment: Is 'enmity' along the right lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Wikipedia section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schadenfreude#English_equivalents) on this word:

> An English expression with a similar meaning is **Roman holiday**, a
>   metaphor from the poem Childe Harold's Pilgrimage by George Gordon,
>   Lord Byron, where a gladiator in Ancient Rome expects to be "butchered
>   to make a Roman holiday" while the audience would take pleasure from
>   watching his suffering. The term suggests debauchery and disorder in
>   addition to sadistic enjoyment.[9]
>
> Another phrase with a meaning similar to Schadenfreude is "**morose
>   delectation**" (delectatio morosa in Latin), meaning, "The habit of
>   dwelling with enjoyment on evil thoughts".[10] The medieval church
>   taught that morose delectation was a sin.[11][12] French writer Pierre
>   Klossowski maintained that the appeal of sadism is morose
>   delectation.[13][14]
>
> An English word of similar meaning is "**gloating**", where "gloat" means
>   "to observe or think about something with triumphant and often
>   malicious satisfaction, gratification, or delight" (e.g. to gloat over
>   an enemy's misfortune).[15] Gloating is differentiated from
>   Schadenfreude in that it does not necessarily require malice (one may
>   gloat to a friend about having defeated him in a game without ill
>   intent), and that it describes an action rather than a state of mind
>   (one typically gloats to the subject of the misfortune or to a third
>   party).

Comment: I quite like 'morose delectation' :)