# A word for a person who hates and wishes bad when someone tries to achieve or do something new

Tags: single-word-requests

Here is an example: I suddenly think about coding (programming) something (I'm a new coder) that I believe I could finish but the other person accidently shows his/her hate and wishes that I fail.

The person I'm talking about is not a coder (programmer).. Just that he/her shows the hate accidently.

Is there a word for such a person?   I'm sure there is but I can't find it.

Comment: **Malicious, malevolent, spiteful, vindictive**.

Comment: Closely related: [Describe someone who doesnt want anything better to happen to anyone else](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/268442/describe-someone-who-doesnt-want-anything-better-to-happen-to-anyone-else/268480#268480) (gives envy, crab mentality, malevolent etc).